# Using Regex Group in C

Tags: c, regex, regex-group

I need to get the groups that matches with my Regex in C to manipulate a Java program logs.

I have tested the Regex:

```c
(Client:\s[a-zA-Z\s]+)|(Wallet:\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+)|(ID\s*:\s*[0-9]{3}.{0,1}[0-9]{3}.{0,1}[0-9]{3}-{0,1}[0-9]{2})
```

[here](https://regexr.com/62fna) and it works.

But in my C program, it doesn't work as well.

```c
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  const char *source =
      "[com.example.app.JavaClass.JavaMethod(JavaClass.java:1)] (Thread-1) - "
      "Client: FirstName MiddleName AnotherName LastName, Wallet: WL01, "
      "Agency: 9999, ID: 06611486123, Ticket: TKR211";
  const char *regexString =
      "(Client:\\s[a-zA-Z[:space:]]+)|(Wallet:\\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+)|(ID\\s*:\\s*[0-"
      "9]{3}.{0,1}[0-9]{3}.{0,1}[0-9]{3}-{0,1}[0-9]{2})";

  regex_t regexCompiled;

  regcomp(&regexCompiled, regexString, REG_ICASE | REG_EXTENDED);

  size_t ngroups = regexCompiled.re_nsub + 1;
  regmatch_t *groups = malloc(ngroups * sizeof(regmatch_t));

  regexec(&regexCompiled, source, ngroups, groups, 0);

  char cursorCopy[strlen(source) + 1];
  strcpy(cursorCopy, source);
  size_t nmatched;
  for (nmatched = 0; nmatched < ngroups; nmatched++) {
    if (groups[nmatched].rm_so == (size_t)(-1)) {
      break;
    }

    char *match =
        calloc(groups[nmatched].rm_eo - groups[nmatched].rm_so, sizeof(char));
    memcpy(match, &source[groups[nmatched].rm_so],
           groups[nmatched].rm_eo - groups[nmatched].rm_so);
    printf("Match: [%2u-%2u]: \"%s\"\n", groups[nmatched].rm_so,
           groups[nmatched].rm_eo, match);
  }
  regfree(&regexCompiled);

  return 0;
}
```

Executing:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings reg.c && ./a.out
```

Generates the output:

```
Match: [70-119]: "Client: FirstName MiddleName AnotherName LastName"
Match: [70-119]: "Client: FirstName MiddleName AnotherName LastName"
```

But what I want is:

```
Match: [xx-xx]: "Client: FirstName MiddleName AnotherName LastName"
Match: [xx-xx]: "Wallet: WL01"
Match: [xx-xx]: "ID: 06611486123"
```

Can someone tell me if it is possible to do using C or I need another approach?

edit:

In my case is possible that some fields ("Client", "Wallet" or "ID") won't coming in log.

Comment: The first difference I notice is the inclusion of `[:space:]` in the C source. Read up on group 0.

Comment: (What is the intention with `.{0,1}`?)

Comment: (`[possible?]` C is considered a universal programming language.)

Comment: What did you try in way of ["debugging"/closely observing program execution](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is composed like this: `(a)|(b)|(c)` where `a`, `b`, and `c` correspond to the `Client` regex, the `Wallet` regex, and the `ID` regex.

This is **not** what you want - you can see in your own [RegExr](https://regexr.com/62fna) that you are not getting one match, but three different matches. In C, you are only matching once.

What you're really trying to accomplish is matching your `source` string **only once**, and having each of the groups contain their string. In other words, we want to change your regex:

`(a)|(b)|(c)` -> `(a),(b),(c)` - one single match matching the *entirety of the string*.

This does the trick:

```
const char *regexString =
    "(Client:\\s[a-zA-Z[:space:]]+), (Wallet:\\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+).*(ID\\s*:\\s*[0-"
    "9]{3}.{0,1}[0-9]{3}.{0,1}[0-9]{3}-{0,1}[0-9]{2})";
```

I changed the first `|` to a `,`  which is what separates the `Client` and `Wallet` substrings, and I changed the second `|` to a `.*` which encapsulates everything between the `Wallet` and `ID` substrings.

Running this now gives:

```
Match: [70-164]: "Client: FirstName MiddleName AnotherName LastName, Wallet: WL01, Agency: 9999, ID: 06611486123"
Match: [70-119]: "Client: FirstName MiddleName AnotherName LastName"
Match: [121-133]: "Wallet: WL01"
Match: [149-164]: "ID: 06611486123"
```

The first line gives you the entire match, while the following lines give you the contents of each separate group.

---

A more visual way of looking at this is going from:

[image]

to:

[image]

Comment: My problem is that is possible not coming all the fields ("Client", "Wallet" or "ID"). If the log come with the value: "Client: FirstName MiddleName AnotherName LastName, Agency: 9999, ID: 06611486123", for example, it returns `segmentation fault`.

Comment: @MatheusRodriguesGuimaraes In that case, you need to restructure your program - you need to call `regexec` in a loop, and on each iteration keep track of `rm_eo` - on the next iteration, begin the search at `source + rm_eo` (and make sure to keep this maintained properly throughout the loop). You won't be able to get what you want with a single call to `regexec`.